# Casting To The Correct Subclass

Tags: java

I hava a supeclass called Car with 3 subclasses.

```
class Ford extends Car{

}

class Chevrolet extends Car{

}


class Audi extends Car{

}
```

Now i have a function called `printMessge(Car car)` which will print a message of a particular car type. In the implementation i  use if statements to test the instance of the classes like this.

```
public int printMessge(Car car){
     if((Ford)car instanceof Ford){
            // print ford

     }else if((Chevrolet)car instanceof Chevrolet){
            // print chevrolet

     }else if((Audi)car instanceof Audi){
            // print Audi
     }
}
```

for instance if i call it for the first time with Ford `printMessge(new Ford())`, it prints the ford message but when i call it with `printMessge(new Chevrolet())`, i get **EXCEPTION**  from the first if statement that Chevrolet cannot be cast to Ford.

What am i doing wrong and what is the best way.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't be casting *before* using `instanceof`. The whole point of `instanceof` is to dynamically test it:

```
if (car instanceof Ford) {
    // You can safely cast to Ford *within* this block
}

...
```

However, if you're in control of these classes it would generally be better to make `printMessage` an abstract method in `Car`, so that each subclass can implement it appropriately themselves. Polymorphism via virtual methods is generally preferred over explicit type testing with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this to fix the runtime errors:

```
public int printMessage(Car car) {
     if (car instanceof Ford) {
            Ford ford = (Ford) car;  // if required
            // print ford

     } else if (car instanceof Chevrolet) {
            Chevrolet chevy = (Chevrolet) car;  // if required
            // print chevrolet

     } else if (car instanceof Audi) {
            Audi audi = (Audi) car;  // if required
            // print Audi
     }
}
```

The idea of the `instanceof` is to test the type of the `car` object so that you can then type cast without the risk of a `ClassCastException`.  But your code was doing the class cast before testing the type.

Having said that, if the `printMessage` method is supposed to print details of the `car` object, you should consider making it an abstract method of `Car` and then implementing it in each of the concrete `Car` subclasses.  When you call `car.printMessage()`, it will dispatch to the actual car's `printMessage()` method ... without any explicit testing and typecasting.  This is what @Jon Skeet means by polymorphism.

(It isn't *always* right (or even possible) to use polymorphism.  For instance, if a `printMessage()` did not conceptually belong on the `Car` class, or if the `Car` API could not be changed.  For such case you can use `instanceof` explicitly or via various design patterns that hide it.)

Answer (score 0):

I think printMessage should be a method of Car class.

Car {

```
  public void print() {
  //do something.
  }
```

}

If needed you can override this function in your subclasses.

Audi extends Car {

```
  @Override
  public void print() {
  //do something.
  }
```

}

```
Car car1 = new Audi();
Car car2 = new Chevrolet();
car1.print();
car2.print(); .....
```